# vim won't launch after installing powerline

Tags: python, macos, vim, vim-powerline

I installed Powerline using `pip install --user git+git://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline`. I then added `rtp+=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim` to my `.vimrc`. Now, when I try to launch vim, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 472, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 405, in get_config_vars
    import re
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

I have Python 2.7 installed via Homebrew. I checked to make sure vim has Python support:

```
$ vim --version | grep +python
+persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile +python -python3 +quickfix
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't really a solution to your problem, but personally I just use the [old non-Python version of Powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) because I found the installation of the new one to be too quarrelsome.

Comment: Your python install seems to be missing a required component. This is most likely to be a Python problem, not a Vim one. Did you try Powerline's issue tracker?

Comment: @romainl: I did check their issue tracker, but no luck. I'll look into whether it's a Python problem as well. Thanks!

Comment: @jessepinho AFAIR in powerline issue tracker is a big bunch of bugs that resolve by not using some default python on Mac OS. I do not remember the differences between pythons on Mac OS X that were talked about.

Comment: @jessepinho, besides browsing that issue tracker you can also create an issue.